# Is it possible to pull the interface name and interface status from this table?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

Ultimately, I would like to be able to have the output in the format of:

'Interface lo is up'

The output is:

['IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = lo', 'IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.1 = up']

['IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = eth0', 'IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.2 = up']

Code:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for errorIndication,errorStatus,errorIndex,varBinds in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(), \
  CommunityData('public', mpModel=0), \
    UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifDescr')),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifOperStatus')),
    lexicographicMode=False):

  table = []
  for varBind in varBinds:
    table.append(varBind.prettyPrint().strip())
    for i in table:
      if i not in table:
        table.append(i)
  print(table)
    for varBind in varBinds:
      table.append(varBind.prettyPrint().strip())
      for i in table:
        if i not in table:
          table.append(i)
    print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resolved PySNMP `ObjectType` consists of an `ObjectIdentity` and a value belonging to a valid SNMP type which is also referred to as an `objectSyntax` in PySNMP. You can access these elements using Python’s standard indexing.

In your loop, `varBinds` is a list consisting of the fully resolved `ObjectType`s corresponding to the two `ObjectIdentity`s you passed to `nextCmd`. You could unpack `varBinds` to reflect each `objectType`, then index into each to get the `objectSyntax`. When you call its `prettyPrint` method, you’ll get the human-readable string that we’re used to.

```py
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for _, _, _, varBinds in nextCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
        UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifDescr')),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifOperStatus')),
        lexicographicMode=False):
    descr, status = varBinds  # unpack the list of resolved objectTypes
    iface_name = descr[1].prettyPrint()  # access the objectSyntax and get its human-readable form
    iface_status = status[1].prettyPrint()
    print("Interface {iface} is {status}"
          .format(iface=iface_name, status=iface_status))
```

Comment: Oliver, I appreciate you input. That worked flawlessly. I struggled with what to do for hours last night. I'm still learning and this helps a lot!!

Comment: Why pretty print then parse? That's a textbook fragile solution. Instead, access the information semantically in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 at the time of writing, I did not look too deeply into PySNMP’s API, but provided an answer that helped the OP, although it was fragile. I looked deeper now and removed the fragile part. I believe you’ll approve this is better.